# Show sudo history in history command?

Tags: linux, centos, command-history

I want to show which user turns to root in history command or in logs  As we have multiple users which turn to root using sudo sudo -i and we are not able to track which users turns root and runs which  command when multiple users turn root at the same time

Comment: In Debian I have `/var/log/auth.log`. Commands run with `sudo` are logged there. In CentOS it may be `/var/log/secure`, I'm not sure. (This is published as a comment, not an answer, because the mentioned file doesn't store what you type in an elevated shell after `sudo -i`; a good answer should cover this as well.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list the commands users have run under `sudo`, you can run

```
grep -E '^sudo' /path/to/their/home/.bash_history
```

Comment: I know the separate history are in user home .bash_history  but suppose a situation multiple users become root at the same time using sudo how would I track which user run which command as the user becomes root all his actions are recorded in that is the reason I am finding the way in which history should print what user becomes root and types the following command as running root

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be found at `/var/log/secure`.

Answer (score 0):

On my version 18 of Linux the `sudo` logs are kept at:

```
/var/log/auth.log
```